# Comparing SQL Dates from various components

Tags: java, swing, datetime, swingx, jspinner

I have created a Java Swing interface which has 4 components

```
spinner      (JXDatePicker)    //get only date in this format yyyy-MM-dd

spinner_1    (JTimeChooser)    //get only time in this format 00-00-00  

spinner_2    (JXDatePicker)    //get only date in this format yyyy-MM-dd

spinner_3    (JTimeChooser)    //get only time in this format 00-00-00
```

All the final dates must be SQL Date and SQL Time and not java.util

I am trying to create two different dates: starting date and ending date

Here the code:

```
        Calendar startingDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        startingDate.setTime(spinner.getDate());

        //This is deprecated
        //Date dt = new Date(spinner.getDate().getTime());
        //dt.getHours();
        //dt.getMinutes();
        //dt.getSeconds();

        Calendar startingDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    //this is an example but it does not point to the right year,month and day
        startingDate.set(startingDate.YEAR, startingDate.MONTH, startingDate.DAY_OF_MONTH, spinner_1.getHours(), spinner_1.getMinutes(), spinner_1.getSeconds());;

        Calendar finishingDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        finishingDate.setTime( spinner_2.getDate());

        Calendar finishingDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    //Same of above
        finishingDateTime.set(finishingDate.YEAR, finishingDate.MONTH, finishingDate.DAY_OF_MONTH, spinner_3.getHours(), spinner_3.getMinutes(), spinner_3.getSeconds());;

        if(startingDateTime.equals(finishingDateTime)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Please insert two different dates.",
                    "Date Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
        }else if(startingDateTime.after(finishingDateTime)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Please the ending date must be after the starting date.",
                    "Date Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;             
        }else{

                    //do something

                    }
```

I would like to create two dates and compare them.

Many methods are deprecated and I think the solution is very easy

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.util.Date startingDate = dateFormat.parse(spinner.getDate());
java.util.Date finishingDate = dateFormat.parse(spinner_2.getDate());
if(enDate.before(stDate)) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

If you want the date and time format, then you can try.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss:ii");
```

Comment: My problem is about retriving date and time from two different components and create a date variable which has the date  from the first component in the "yyyy-MM-dd" format and the time of the second component in the 00-00-00  format. Afterwards I need to do the same process for the last two components and then compare the two created dates.

Comment: You can use finishingDate.getTime() to get the time of second component. It will return time in milliseconds from 1-Jan-1970, but for comparison this would be good enough.

Comment: I need to use the created dates later to query a sql database, see what I did in my answer to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way

```
    Calendar startingDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        startingDate.setTime(spinner.getDate());            
        startingDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,spinner_1.getHours());
        startingDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE,spinner_1.getMinutes());
        startingDate.set(Calendar.SECOND,spinner_1.getSeconds());


        Calendar finishingDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        finishingDate.setTime( spinner_2.getDate());            
        finishingDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,spinner_3.getHours());
        finishingDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE,spinner_3.getMinutes());
        finishingDate.set(Calendar.SECOND,spinner_3.getSeconds());


        if(startingDate.equals(finishingDate)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Please insert two different dates.",
                    "Date Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
        }else if(startingDate.after(finishingDate)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Please the ending date must be after the starting date.",
                    "Date Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;             
        }else{
                    //do something
                    }
```